# FireBase and Php (Laravel)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, firebase

I have a Laravel + mySQL app that use either *ajax* or *Angular $http service* and I want to integrate websockets into that mix.

So I thought of trying Firebase, which is great and easy to use, but am a bit confused about a couple of things. I am seeking for someone's help in clearing that confusion.

1. is it possible to change the app url name for firebase ?
   So instead of something like `https://vivid-torch-xxx.firebaseio.com` can I change it to `https://myawesomesite.firebaseio.com`?
2. how the schema on Firebase should be structured ?
   Or better yet how not to use it all and just use Firebase as websocket server instead of ajax ?
   I essentially don't want to have 2 databases to manage the data.
3. there is a Firebase package for php/laravel, but I don't know why would I need it. Or what exactly is the benefit of using it if am already using a REST-ful backend with angular.

Comment: 1. Sure, just create a Firebase named "myawesomesite". 2 and 3 are unanswerable. Just start working on your application and come back with concrete questions (and preferable snippets of code and data.

Comment: okey thanx, i got the first one sorted out ,for the other 2 i was hoping someone with a previous experience with `php and firebase` could help with some info or what he went through on using both.

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately that sort of question is off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Firebase is a "JSON data store that automatically synchronizes changes between all connected clients". If you are looking for a websocket library, I would recommend looking elsewhere: https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=php%20websocket.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i know its a bit rare and more of a single case but i thought i would give it a shot maybe someone runs into it and give some advice ,btw thanx for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema will basically be how you want your JSON for your front-end will read it. Are you displaying notifications? Then investigate how that would be structured. Firebase will give you the power to push updates to the front-end which then will no longer have to pull data via the API on what the actual data is it needs to display the notification.